# Nvidia GTX250( Ubuntu 12.10 64) after install drivers video change to 1600x1200(without left panel, without borders(file,help,go))

Tags: nvidia, 12.10

Nvidia GTX250( Ubuntu 12.10 64) after install drivers - 304.51.really.304.43-0ubuntu1(there was x3 point of 96, 173, current- video change to 1600x1200(without left panel, without borders(file,help,go)). I opened (by right mouse lick) and changed to 1024x768 = lines and nothing else(but ubuntu works! So how repair it back to normal? Thank's for all how will tell me how to! (Sorry about my English).

Comment: I can lauch root terminal by recovery mod!

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? I'm having this exact issue as well. Going back to the open source driver is painful.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on my Lenovo t410 (Ubuntu 12.10, nVidia gt218 NVS 3100M).
I returned to a normal view as follows:

1. open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)
2. type `software-center` in it and the sofware center will show up.
3. Then go to "edit" (close to the file menu...I have it in italian and don't exactly know what it is in english) and look for "software sources". The software source will open.
4. There you go to the last tab, "additional drivers".
5. You can change back to the open source driver, which should work.

Comment: Thanks for answer!But what is mean (lele)in your post)?

Comment: This gets me back to the open source driver, but using that driver everything is fuzzy on my monitor. Bleh. (btw lele is the username of the poster of this answer)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a "user friendly" way to do the change stated by Evandro Silva.

When you get to the screen without a "desktop", click the right button on your mouse and open "Change Desktop Background". When you are there, click on "All Settings". Go to the "System" sub-menu and click on "Software Sources". Then go to "Additional Drivers" and revert back (select it) from the menu, as stated by Silva.

Although easy, not everyone is familiar with the "Terminal", so this is a good way to explain customers how to do this without the need to know how to use terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Can You launch your terminaL ?

Comment: I can lauch root terminal by recovery mod!

Comment: http://wiki.compiz.org/Troubleshooting  .. see here . It is the trouble of created by 'compiz'  after restart! Try to solve it in this way !